# variant is not assigning the float

Tags: c++, c++17, variant

```
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>
using namespace std;
 
int main()
{
    variant<int, float> var{0.23};
    if(holds_alternative<float>(var)){
        if(var.index() == 1){
            cout << get<float>(var) << endl;
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The initialization should work but instead it gives the following error:

> main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
> main.cpp:7:33: error: no matching function for call to 'std::variant<int, float>::variant()'

I'm not sure if I made a mistake in the code.

Answer (score 2):

`0.23` is `double`. You should use `0.23f`, which is `float`, instead.

Answer (score 1):

The initialization failed because of the narrowing conversion inside the curly braces. so use

```
   variant<int, float> var{0.23f};
```

instead.

Note that `0.23` is a double literal, not a `float` one.

See [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/7TaKE5)